# NoReverseMatch в Django

Tags: python, html, django

помогите, пожалуйста, с моей проблемой. Пытался как мог, но не нашел исправления ошибки.

> NoReverseMatch at /news/ Reverse for 'theory' with arguments '(1,)'
> not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['theory/int:theory_id']

views.py

```
@login_required
def news(request):
    posts = Lessons.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'landing/../static/news.html', {'posts' : posts})
```

```
@login_required
def theory(request,theory_id):
    return HttpResponse(f"Отображение статьи с id = {theory_id}")
```

urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
    from django.contrib import admin
    from landing import views
    from django.urls import path, re_path
    from lessons.models import *
    from .views import *
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.landing, name='landing'),
        url(r'news/$', views.news, name='news'),
        url(r'contacts/$', views.contacts, name='contacts'),
        url(r'aboutus/$', views.aboutus, name='aboutus'),
        url(r'theory/<int:theory_id>',views.theory, name='theory'),
        url(r'newwords/$',views.newwords, name='newwords'),
        url(r'practice/$',views.practice, name='practice'),
        url(r'register/$',views.registerPage, name='register'),
    ]
```

проблемная часть в шаблоне news

```
    {% for p in posts %}
            <div class="col-md-3 mt-3">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow border-dark">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">Урок №1</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <a href="{% url 'theory' p.pk %}" >
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark">Старт</button>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Вы не правильно передали аргументы для url-a с именем theory.

Comment: Помню была у кого-то похожая проблема. Возможно это из-за использования функции url. попробуйте использовать path для создания пути с именем theory. Это просто мои догадки, но попробовать все же стоит

Comment: @Миша нет, передал он правильно, не правильно определил шаблон урл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не `url`, а `path`.

[Django urlpatterns](https://django.fun/docs/django/ru/3.1/topics/http/urls/)

`path` - это новый способ задания шаблонов `url` в `django`. Ранее использовался только `url`, теперь возможны оба варианта.

Ваш шаблон url должен выглядеть так

```
        # Вариант с path
        path(r'theory/<int:theory_id>',views.theory, name='theory'), 
 
        # Вариант с url
        url(r'^theory/(?P<theory_id>[\d]+)/$',views.theory, name='theory'),

        # Оставьте только один из вариантов, либо с path, либо с url
```

`path` доступен в `django.urls.path`

---

PS: Шаблоны урлов через `url` нужно начинать с `^`, чтобы избежать лишних проблем, подробнее можете почитать в старой документации, для django 1.11 или 2.0 (не помню когда добавили `path`)